# computing $\int \overline z^k dz$, $k \geq1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help me to compute the integrals $\int \overline z^k\,dz$, $k \geq1$ and $\int z^k \,\left|dz\right|$ over a positive oriented unit circle centered at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Parametrize the circle by letting $z(\theta)=1+e^{i\theta}$ and $z'(\theta)=ie^{i\theta}$ with $0\leq\theta<2\pi$ and use the definition of conjugation and line integrals. Now we can calculate: $$\int_\gamma\overline{z}^k\,dz=\int_0^{2\pi}(1+e^{-i\theta})^k\cdot ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta.$$Use the binomial theorem, and then since the summation is finite, you can interchange the sum and integral.

Comment: the circle is centered at 1, not at origin

Comment: @Mathematician: My hint has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

We take the standard parametrisation $e^{i t}$ with $t\in [0,2\pi]$
Than we have 
$$\int_\gamma \overline{z}^k  \mathrm{d}z= i  \int_0^{2\pi}e^{(1-k)t} \mathrm{d}t=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{rl}
     2 \cdot  \pi i & k=1\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: what would be the difference for $|dz|$?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what the $|dz|$  actual means, never met that notation

Comment: $|dz|=-ir\frac{dz}{z}$ when $|z|=r$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: $|dz|$ just means $|z'(\theta)|\,d\theta$.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was a typo. I'll edit to keep $\left|dz\right|$.

Comment: @mathematician than beside the minus nothing should change