# How to make sense of $\int _{\gamma }f(z)\,\left|dz\right|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, path-connected, semi-riemannian-geometry

**Context**

I understand from [1] that to define the contour integral, let $f:\mathbb {C} \to \mathbb {C} $ be a continuous function on the directed smooth curve $\gamma$.   Then the integral along  $\gamma$   is denoted
$$\int _{\gamma }f(z)\,dz.$$

For a research project that I am working on in pseudo-Riemannian I would like to define a "path integral" with the norm of the differential. I mean like
$$\int _{\gamma }f(z)\,\left|dz\right|.\tag{1}$$

My questions are open ended and I am generally soliciting not just answers to my questions but broader comments. Any citations to integrals with the norm of a differential (as in Eq. 1) would be welcome.

**Questions**

1. Is it nonsensical to define a "path integral" as in Eq. 1?
2. Can I restrict the functions $f$ so that the "path integral" in Eq. 1 makes sense?
3. Can I restrict the smooth curves $\gamma$ so that the "path integral" in Eq. 1 makes sense?
4. Can you provide any citations to a book that has an integral with the norm of a complex differential?
5. Are there any other points/details/objects that are important to consider as I attempt to work with "path integrals" as in Eq. 1?

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration

Comment: Do you mean $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb C?$ $z$ is not a function.

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724423/metric-and-curvature-on-a-riemann-surface I see the norm of a differential and a citation to two books on the subject....

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749950/how-to-mesure-lengths-and-areas-in-other-euclidean-spherical-and-hyperbolic-geo, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669177/hyperbolic-metric-with-respect-to-pi-mathbbh-rightarrow-delta, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30224/i-dont-understand-this-step-in-my-professors-boardwork I also the norm of a differential

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319932/computing-int-overline-zk-dz-k-geq1 a comment states that $|dz|=−ir\frac{dz}{z}$ when $|z|=r$, while another comment states that $|dz|$ just means $|z′(θ)|dθ$.

Comment: J. B. Conway in Chapter 4 of his second edition "Funtions of one complex variables" (Springer) defines $$\int\limits_{\gamma} f(z)\, |dz|,$$  
as 
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))d|\gamma|(t),$$
where $\gamma$ is a rectifiable curve from $[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ and $|\gamma|:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is the variation function $V(\gamma;[a,t])$ defined by 
$$|\gamma|(t)=V(\gamma;[a,t]) = \sup\{|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})| \, ; \{t_0,\dots, t_{k}\} \,\,\text{is a partition of $[a,t]$}\}.$$

Comment: Future readers: See Definition 1.16 in Conway, "Functions of one complex variable," Springer-Verlag, 1973, page 64.